# Not sure how to setup view object and connect with IBOutlet code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, interface-builder

I am trying trying to copy all of the functionality of this example app provided by Apple called AVCam: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

I am 99% done with copying this code, but I just have one final problem. I have an IBOutlet statement that looks like this: `@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet MediaCapturePreviewView *previewView;`

According to the Apple sample code, this outlet is supposed to be connected to a View object that has been placed on top of the normal/default view.

Here is a screenshot of what the Connections Inspector looks like in the Apple example:

[image]

You will notice that the IBOutlet called "previewView" has been connected to something called the "Cam Preview View".

Also, in this screenshot, you can see that I am able to select this View object by itself and that it shows a Referencing Outlet in it's connections inspector for the same IBOutlet and View Object:

[image]

My problem is that I cannot get the IBOutlet code to connect to this View Object. I have tried the normal behavior of clicking and dragging to make the connections but it just wants to create a new outlet. It will not let me connect to the outlet that I have already created.

I have been playing with this for 2 hours now and just can't get it to work like Apple's sample code.

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: are you trying to connect the outlet into your own view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .xib file, make sure that  `UIView` class is assigned as `AVCamPreviewView`  instead of `UIView`.

[image]

Comment: This worked. Thank you Ramshad. The custom class had not been set yet. I just changed it and was finally able to make the connection between the IBOutlet statement and the View object. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

A few possible solutions:

1. Save the file with the IBOutlet you're trying to connect up (the source code, not the IB)
2. Clean, rebuild
3. Restart Xcode.

Comment: Is the view controller on which the view is placed set to the right file owner?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to objective-c and the xcode IDE. How can I check this?